# How to iterate through Swift struct and set the value of each object?

Tags: swift, struct

I currently have the structure below, and what I'd like to do is iterate through each variable and set it to a random integer (using `Int(arc4random_uniform(52))`).

Is there a way to do this? I've tried searching for similar questions, but they suggest creating an array that contains my struct and iterating the array way, which doesn't seem to work properly.

```
struct SevenCardStruct {
            var firstCardString: Int
            var secondCardString: Int
            var thirdCardString: Int
            var fourthCardString: Int
            var fifthCardString: Int
            var sixthCardString: Int
            var seventhCardString: Int
        }
```

Comment: use an array. Everything else is just a workaround.

Comment: @Sulthan How would I do it using an array for this case?

Comment: `let sevenCards: [Int] = (1...7).map { _ in Int(arc4random_uniform(52)) }`

Answer (score 0):

Without implementing an array one option is to use the implicit memberwise initializer

```
struct SevenCardStruct {
  var firstCardString: Int
  var secondCardString: Int
  var thirdCardString: Int
  var fourthCardString: Int
  var fifthCardString: Int
  var sixthCardString: Int
  var seventhCardString: Int
}

func random() -> Int
{
  return Int(arc4random_uniform(52))
}

let card = SevenCardStruct(firstCardString: random(), secondCardString: random(), thirdCardString: random(), fourthCardString: random(), fifthCardString: random(), sixthCardString: random(), seventhCardString: random())
```